# Regexp_Extract BigQuery anything up to "|"

Tags: sql, string, google-bigquery

I'm fairly new to coding and I was wondering if you could give me a hand writing some regular expression for BigQuery SQL.

Basically I would like to extract everything before the bar sign "|" for one of my column.

Example:

- Source string:
  bla-BLABLA-cid=123456_sept1220_blabla--potato-Blah|someMore_string_stuff-IDontNeed
- Desired output:
  bla-BLABLA-cid=123456_sept1220_blabla--potato-Blah

I thought about using the REGEXP_EXTRACT(string, delimiter) function but I'm totally unable to write some regex (LOL). Therefore I had a look over Stack, and have found stuff like:

```
SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT( String_Name , "\S*\s*\|" ) ,
# or 
SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT( String_Name , '.+?(?=|)')
```

But every time I get error messages like " invalid perl operator: (?= " or "Illegal escape space"

Would you have any suggestions on why I get these messages and/or how could I proceed to extract these strings?

Many many thanks in advance <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SPLIT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#split) instead:

```
SELECT SPLIT("bla-BLABLA-cid=123456_sept1220_blabla--potato-Blah|someMore_string_stuff-IDontNeed", "|")[OFFSET(0)]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Prefix the pattern string with `r`:

```
SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT(String_Name, r'\S*\s*\|')
```

This is the syntax for a *raw string* constant.  You can review what this means in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/lexical).

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately this gives me the error : Cannot parse regular expression: invalid perl operator: (?=

Comment: @AlexandraMorel-Fonteray . . . That is a different issue, that BQ regular expressions don't have back references.  I meant to grab the first regular expression for the example.